# How do I make the Toast appear?

Tags: reactjs

I've made a custom Toast (`<Toast />`) that notifies users with information. I want the toast to shows users a message when a request fails or succeeds. This is how I tried to do it, however nothing is displayed.

```
const SignUp = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');

  const postData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/signup', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({username: ''})
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    if (response.status === 200) {
      return <Toast title={'Success'} description={"This isn't working"} />;
    } else {
      return <Toast title={'Error'} description={"This isn't working"} />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="Sign-container">
       <input
            type="text"
            value={username}
            onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)}
       />
       <button className="Sign-button" onClick={() => postData()}>
          SIGNUP
       </button>

      <Toast title={'Test'} description={'This Works'} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a state called `toastTitle` and change it according to the response status and in your render function bind the Toast title to the already created state, then create hide it after some time :

```
const SignUp = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
const [toast, setToast] = useState({title:'',msg:''});

  const postData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/signup', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({username: ''})
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    if (response.status === 200) {
       setToast({title:'Success',msg:'this  works'})
    } else {
      setToast({title:'Error',msg:'this does not work'})
    }
    
    setTimeout(()=>{setToast({title:'',msg:'})},3000) // reset it after 3s
  };

  return (
    <div className="Sign-container">
       <input
            type="text"
            value={username}
            onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)}
       />
       <button className="Sign-button" onClick={() => postData()}>
          SIGNUP
       </button>

     {toast.title && <Toast title={toast.title} description={toast.msg} />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to conflate a click handler with creating/rendering a component.

What you want to do is have the click handler trigger a *state change*. The changed state will then trigger a render event and you can re-render your component with the correct elements with respect to the newly changed state.

That is the React Way™.